# What are valid and typical names for Cargo manifest files? (Cargo.toml)

Tags: rust-cargo

Most projects using have Cargo.toml , but I've seen some cases of Cargo used with other .toml files.

- Are these complete outliers?
- Are there conventions for alternative names?
- How would to identify a Cargo.toml file under another name? (ie: it must have packages and dependencies sections)

Background: I am writing a utility that aims to find all Cargo.toml files. If there are alternative names for Cargo.toml I want to make sure I spot those too.